# How to make my office app run just by double click

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, office365, office-app

I have created an office app and if i run it through `VS2013` the `task pane` is getting loaded well.

But what i want is to run my xls file just by double clicking on it.

I tried by publishing the web app in `IIS` and publish the office app by using the published website in the `IIS` which generated the office `AppManifest` for me.

I don't know how to use those to run my `xls` file just by double clicking it.

What i mean is if i debug from VS2013 this is how my xls file look like with the Task pane right side.
[image]

This `TestXl` belongs to my solution

[image]

If i double click the `TestXl` this is how my xl file look like with the error

[image]

what i want is i should see the same xl file in fig 1 when i double click the `TestXl`

Comment: Are you saying that you want the app you've written to be the default when opening .xls files?  Or are you saying that you've created a .xls file and want it to open in Office when you double-click it?

Comment: .xls files are Excel workbooks, and they don't *run*. They load in Excel, which in turn runs any code in the workbook. Double-clicking an .xls file should automatically start Excel and load that workbook if Excel is installed on the system. It won't do anything if Excel is not (although Windows will prompt you to choose an app with which to open it). I don't know what IIS or web publishing has to do with anything.

Comment: We don't know what your code for that Task pane is doing, but it's clearly trying to access something on a network or internet connection that isn't available from your web server (which is clearly stated in the error text).

Comment: What are the properties that determine what is displayed in that task pane?  My guess is that you have a hardcoded path in it that only exists when running in debug mode, and doesn't exist anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This a bit of a long shot but.... 
Try opening Excel first instead of using 'Start' to debug, then from your Visual Studio solution click on the Debug menu -> 'Attach to Process' and select EXCEL.EXE from the list of available processes.

then open your xls file.

I hope it will address you issue.

Comment: What i want to do is to give my TestXl file to the end user, who doesn't have VS.

Comment: I understand that, but you wanted to debug you xls file. I give you that option.

Comment: I don't want to debug the xls. I am done with development. Now what i want to do is to give this xls file and any supporting files needed to run to some one.

Comment: this wasn't understand from question. Anyhow, Compile your project in release and try to load it not from the run button in VS but from the release folder by double clicking the xls file.